# Separating generic type definition of function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, haskell

For instance, in Haskell, having corresponding standalone definitions for each type and function is the standard way to define a function.

The definition of  `id` in Haskell is:

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
id = \a -> a
```

In TypeScript, we can write

```
const id = <T>(a: T) => a;
```

but often, I want to define similarly in the manner of Haskell.

```
type id<T> = (a:T) => T 
const id:id<T> = a => a;
```

This generates an error: **Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)**

**Please note:**

I know the code below works,

```
type id<T> = (a: T) => T
const id: id<number> = a => a;
```

but my Question is for

```
const id = <T>(a: T) => a;
```

Is there any proper way to write in the separation manner?

TypeScript Version 4.5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type id = <T>(a: T) => T
const id: id = a => a;
```